# Scripts/Engine for Self-Arranged Ads?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ads

I had a horrible time wording the title of this post, but basically, I run a small niche site and have arranged with a brick and mortar business to have a context-specific link to their site advertising their products (like a 'buy this from this store' link).

We would bill them every month for how many clicks that they get. What's a fair way to do this? The obvious solution is to just get them to check how many clicks they get from our domain, but we want to avoid offloading work to them. We could record clicks using an in-between URL, but how would they trust us?

Are there scripts/engines out there that will facilitate this, preferably even automate the billing? The one requirement is that there should be no cuts to a middle man. Also keep in mind that this is not really an ad in the traditional sense, it's just a context specific link.

We're using ruby on rails if that helps or matters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically describing an affiliate link. Use the "in between URL" option and count the clicks on your end. Add some token param that they can mine out of their own logs if they really want to, but you can keep a count on your own end for billing.

For example.

1. End user clicks on: http://yoursite/outbound/1
2. Your controller counts the click and redirects to: http://theirsite/path?foo=abc123
3. Make the `foo=abc123` something that you both are aware of, so that they can log it on their end if they really care to do so.
4. Send them the bill.

I'm advocating the simple approach here, because this sounds like a small time operation where you and the owner are in close communication. If you really didn't trust each other, then this deal probably wouldn't be happening at all, right?

Comment: We do have a good relationship. My only worry is that I'm not entirely sure of the order of magnitude of clicks we'll get, the links are very relevant. If I estimate say 1,000 clicks in the first month and they get 10,000 wouldn't they be required to see if that checks out? I suppose in the end, it'd be fairly easy for them to verify a large spike in traffic, I just wanted to see if there were nerdier solutions out there.

Comment: I would think that on their end something like Google Analytics could easily tell them if your counts were at all close. There's going to be variance based on people not having JavaScript enabled, or blocking scripts in general, but most clicks should register.